# Error in app.js file that I can't crack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular, express

I'm getting an unexpected token error when I try to run the following app.js code via node. It says the problem is on or around line 15. Am I missing a bracket or something? It's probably something simple, but I just don't see it.

[image]

Comment: Take a good hard look at line 15...it has a closing brace and a closing param that do not appear to have any corresponding openers.  You have the same issue on line 8.

Comment: @koberlander please post code instead of image

Comment: @Sajeetharan is right. You may want to consider using a linter, it will save you from these kinds of errors. ESLint is a great one.

Comment: I hadn't heard of this before and just installed it. Tried to have it examine one of my files, but no luck. Gonna dig into the docs and try again. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to identify them when you look at it, you have extra closing paranthesis in line no 8 and 15  **`});`**,

also remove declaring the module twice, its not needed.

remove line number 14.

Corrected code,

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var angular = require("angular");
angular.module('NoteWrangler', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);
app.use(express.static('AWS-Portfolio'));
app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Listening on port 3000');
});
```

Comment: same answer I was about to post.

Comment: i think david posted the same answer as comment above before us

Comment: That he did. Shame he didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks to all that offered suggestions. Sometimes when you stare at something too long you overlook stupid stuff. :)

Comment: @Sajeetharan thanks for the code! It took care of all of my token illegal problems. However, now it has a problem with line 3. Is it because I use the variable name to call the function?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Tried, but no luck. Then, it doesn't know what angular is when I use it in the next line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142364/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-koberlander).